# pandas - read file only to a certain limit

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file (in GBs) and want to read out only (let's say) 500MB of it. Is there a way I can do this?

PS: I thought of reading in first few lines of the dataset. See how much memory it uses and then accordingly get the number of lines. I'm looking for a way that can avoid this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator here to read lines from a file in a memory efficient way, you can refer to this [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

or 
you can use f.read(number of lines) to read from line,  lets suppose you want to read first 100 lines in a file

```
fname='your file name'
with open(fname) as f:
    lines=100
    content = f.read(lines)
    print content
```

or

by using pandas nrows (number of rows)

```
import pandas as pd
myfile = pd.read('your file name',nrows=1000)
```